# Laravel mailable subject not working if I queue the mailable

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm working with laravel 7.0 and for some reason when I write subject in my build method of a mailable and queue it by calling the queue method of the Mail facade the subject isn't changing, it is taking the mailable classname and setting it as the subject. If I hard code the `$subject` variable in the mailable class it works and if I don't queue it then the subject gets set. Anybody knows how to solve this? I'm using database driver to handle the queue.

**Mailable build method**

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject(config('app.name') . ' OTP')
         ->markdown('emails.otp');
}
```

**How I'm queuing up the mail to send**

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail::to($this->user->email)
            ->queue(new \App\Mail\Otp($generatedOtp));
```

Comment: Hey, did you test with a static subject ?

Comment: Yes. The problem is solved. I was using `queue:work` to run my queue. Running the queue with `queue:listen` solved the issue.

Comment: Why? What is the difference between queue:work and queue:listen? I thought it was the same.